# Transactions with IF statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, transactions, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a transaction that checks if a customer exists, if not, insert the customer. Then update in flight bookings where records reference this customer:

```
BEGIN;
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM LeadCustomer WHERE CustomerID = 20006)
  INSERT INTO LeadCustomer VAlUES(20006, 'Tom', 'Mann', '08, Lilac Street, Oxford', 
  'tomisawesome@gmail.com');
  ROLLBACK;
  UPDATE flightBooking Set NumSeats + 2, TotalCost + 100 WHERE EXISTS (CustomerID = 20006);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Problem is that it doesn't like 'IF'. Why is this? How do I get round this problem? 
Many thanks,
Callum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `IF` statement properly. It expects the `THEN` keyword after the condition, and should be terminated with `END IF`.

Also, the syntax of your `UPDATE` statement is not valid SQL.

Finally, I don't see the intent of the `ROLLBACK` after the `INSERT`, so I removed it - and the `commit` command needs to be removed from the code block (pl/pgsql does not support transactions).

Consider:

```
DO $$
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM LeadCustomer WHERE CustomerID = 20006) THEN
        INSERT INTO LeadCustomer 
        VAlUES(20006, 'Tom', 'Mann', '08, Lilac Street, Oxford', 'tomisawesome@gmail.com');
    END IF;

    UPDATE flightBooking 
    SET NumSeats  = NumSeats + 2, TotalCost = TotalCost + 100 
    WHERE CustomerID = 20006;

END;
$$
```

Note that you need to wrap the code in a `DO` block.